# How to convert string column values using dictionarty and regular expression in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to convert the `Result` col `Kolkata Knight Riders won by 140 runs` to `KKR` and so on... for whole column.I have converted `Team1` and `Team2` using this code snippet.

```
# short_name = [x for x in input().split(' ')]
# full_name = df.Team1.unique().tolist()
# temp = {}
# for key in full_name:
#     for value in short_name:
#         temp[key] = value
#         short_name.remove(value)
#         break


#changing the values of team name into their short forms
full_name = ['ROYAL CHALLENGERS BANGALORE',
 'KINGS XI PUNJAB',
 'DELHI CAPITALS',
 'KOLKATA KNIGHT RIDERS',
 'MUMBAI INDIANS',
 'RAJASTHAN ROYALS',
 'DECCAN CHARGERS',
 'CHENNAI SUPER KINGS',
 'KOCHI TUSKERS KERALA',
 'PUNE WARRIORS',
 'SUNRISERS HYDERABAD',
 'GUJARAT LIONS',
 'RISING PUNE SUPERGIANT']
short_name = ['RCB',
 'KXP',
 'DELHI',
 'KKR',
 'MI',
 'RR',
 'DECCAN',
 'CSK',
 'KTK',
 'PW',
 'SH',
 'GL',
 'RPS']

        
df.Team1 = df.Team1.replace(temp,regex=True)
df.Team2 = df.Team2.replace(temp,regex=True)


df.Team1 = df.Team1.str.replace(' ','')
df.Team2 = df.Team2.str.replace(' ','')
```

```
{'ROYAL CHALLENGERS BANGALORE': 'RCB',
 'KINGS XI PUNJAB': 'KXP',
 'DELHI CAPITALS': 'DELHI',
 'KOLKATA KNIGHT RIDERS': 'KKR',
 'MUMBAI INDIANS': 'MI',
 'RAJASTHAN ROYALS': 'RR',
 'DECCAN CHARGERS': 'DECCAN',
 'CHENNAI SUPER KINGS': 'CSK',
 'KOCHI TUSKERS KERALA': 'KTK',
 'PUNE WARRIORS': 'PW',
 'SUNRISERS HYDERABAD': 'SH',
 'GUJARAT LIONS': 'GL',
 'RISING PUNE SUPERGIANT': 'RPS'}
```

I want Result column to covert the string into key of temp dictionary if it matches using regex

temp key has the keyword to find in Result column string and convert it into dictionary values.

[Notebook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsp5Q.jpg)

Notebook Link: https://www.kaggle.com/ankitkalauni/ipl-eda-beginner?scriptVersionId=73264395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data =['Kolkata Knight Riders won by 140 runs', 'Chennai Super Kings won by 33 runs', 'Delhi Daredevils won by 9 wickets (with 29']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Result'])

dic = {'ROYAL CHALLENGERS BANGALORE': 'RCB', 'KINGS XI PUNJAB': 'KXP', 'DELHI CAPITALS': 'DELHI', 'KOLKATA KNIGHT RIDERS': 'KKR', 'MUMBAI INDIANS': 'MI', 'RAJASTHAN ROYALS': 'RR', 'DECCAN CHARGERS': 'DECCAN', 'CHENNAI SUPER KINGS': 'CSK', 'KOCHI TUSKERS KERALA': 'KTK', 'PUNE WARRIORS': 'PW', 'SUNRISERS HYDERABAD': 'SH', 'GUJARAT LIONS': 'GL', 'RISING PUNE SUPERGIANT': 'RPS'}
df['Result'] = df['Result'].str.split(' won').str[0].str.upper() #extract name by splitting string, convert to upper case to map with the dict
df['Result'] = df['Result'].map(dic)
```

Output:

|  | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | KKR |
| 1 | CSK |
| 2 | nan |

You'll see that Delhi Daredevils are not mapped as they're not in the dict. If you wish to keep the old value you can use `replace` in stead of `map`.

Comment: after replacing the values of the Result column, there are more values than in the dictionary like match tied, abandoned etc. and the Delhi Daredevils is a typo the real team is Delhi Capitals, I will try to do the same for Tied and Abandoned.